# Magento installed in a subdirectory

Tags: magento

Hi I currently have a site setup where magento is installed in a subdirectory called magento

ie. 
http://domainname.com/magento/

So the base URL is set as http://domainname.com/magento/ and secure base URL is https://domainname.com/magneto/

What do I need to do to get it so everything working so it can be referenced as http://domainname.com

Comment: Physically move the files, or change the webserver settings to point to www/magento/ instead. Is there any reason why you can't just move the files it is much easier :)

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can achieve this by using.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/magento/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /magento/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ magento/index.php [L]
```

for reference  you can see [change-main-domain-to-subfolder](http://chanon.info/change-main-domain-to-subfolder/399/)

Answer (score 2):

Change DocumentRoot in Apache Http Server's config file. `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` or `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. change it to `/var/www/html/magento` or `/srv/www/htdocs/magento` according to your os.